# WebClient doesn't seem to work?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

I've got the following code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("whatever"));
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
```

and:

```
void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  Stream reply = (Stream)e.Result;
  StreamReader s;
  s = new StreamReader(reply);
  this._code = s.ReadToEnd();
  s.Close();
}
```

While debugging I can see the compiler doesn't move into the `client_OpenReadCompleted` event. Where's the mistake? I already tried using `DownloadStringCompleted` and `DownloadStringAsync` instead, but this doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you actually have connectivity and the target URI is resolvable?  Since none of the answers proposed work, it's reasonable to assume that your environment itself is the problem.

Comment: R u behind any proxy server (usual case with corporate networks). If so that could be causing the issue in emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice you to not use the WebClient since this has a negative impact on your UI because the callback will always return on the UI thread because of a bug.

Here is explained why and how you can use HttpWebRequest as an alternative

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8

Comment: I replaced my code, same problem. Now the debugger doesn't move into the ResponseCallback method. =/

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your project or anything if this and the other solutions posted here are not working. did you try to start a new fresh project to test this piece of code?

Comment: Why do you say that returning to UI thread is a bug? IIRC, this is by design, and on "big" desktop .Net it behaves the same - just like BackgroundWorker. Those components were designed to easily interact with GUI and that means pushing the results on the UI thread, so UI controls can be safely updated

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the event handler before you call the async method.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("www.google.it"));
```

**EDIT:** I have tested this snippet inside LINQPad and it works for me.

```
void Main()
{
    var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
    client.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        "Read successfully".Dump();
    };
    client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.it"));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Are you sure there is no exception inside your code?

Comment: I have tested it with LinqPad4 and it works for me.. Try to see the edit!

Comment: The change has no effect. I know, usually it has to work... So the mistake has to be somewhere else... But I have no idea where that could be.

Comment: I think it is possible that your issue is due to a specific WP7 behaviour, have you tried following http://stackoverflow.com/users/347112/vdcruijsen-net advice?

Comment: Yes, I did. The same problem =/

Answer (score 1):

Your order of operations is incorrect.

```
//create an instance of webclient
WebClient client = new WebClient();
//assign the event handler
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
//call the read method
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("whatever"));
```